# Self-matching regex

Tags: popularity-contest, regular-expression

**Write a non-trivial regex that matches itself.**

For example, `#.*$` will match a comment outside of a string in python until the end-of-line, and also matches itself in perl regex syntax.

**Rules**:

- The regular expression must do something useful or practical.
- Tell what regex syntax you are using (e.g. perl or POSIX).
- Winner is the highest voted compliant answer.
- Be creative!

Comment: There was a question on SO a while ago, whether there is a regex that matches valid regexes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression

Comment: @padde Very interesting! :)  In the comments, they said that regex doesn't match itself, but it apparently matches all non-recursive regex.  Too bad--that would likely be a winning entry (matching itself and all other entries).

Comment: Define non-trivial. I mean, OK, `A` would be trivial, but where do you draw the line? And by "self-matching" do you mean it can _only_ match itself, or is it allowed to match other strings too? Would `.` qualify?

Comment: @MrLister Non-trivial would be decided by voters.  Self-matching means that it matches itself, but part of it being useful/practical means that it matches other things too.  `.` qualifies as a self-matching regex, but that's also pretty trivial.  So is `ABC123Hello World`.

Comment: @padde which actually wasn't a regex because the grammar that describes regular expression is context-free.

Comment: @FUZxxl yes, that is true but one could still write a regex that matches other regexes, but doesnt care about the validity of the matched regexes.

Comment: @padde Well, what is an invalid regex then? An invalid regex obviously isn't a regex. So you essentially say: "yes, that is true but one could still write a regex that matches other regexes, but doesnt care if the matched regex really is a regex" (sic!)

Comment: @FUZxxl, "regex" and "regular expression" parted ways many years ago. Now the relationships between them are i) an inclusion; and ii) an etymological link.

Comment: What does the winner get?

Comment: `/.+/` Matches itself and can be used to determine if a string is empty or not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
/(^|[^/])\/(?!\/)(\[.+?]|\\.|[^/\r\n])+\/[gim]{0,3}(?=\s*($|[\r\n,.;})]))/g
```

Stolen from https://github.com/LeaVerou/prism/blob/gh-pages/components/prism-javascript.js. This should match (in JavaScript) all JavaScript regular expressions.

Answer (score 11):

### PYTHON

Below is a self-matching regex generator. You provide two lists, one contains training data that the regex should match (in addition to matching itself), the other contains training data the the regex should *NOT* match:

```python
from random import choice, randrange
import re
from itertools import zip_longest, chain, islice
from operator import itemgetter

CHAR_SET = [chr(i) for i in range(128)] + [r"\\", r"\d", r"\D",
                                           r"\w", r"\W", r"\s",
                                           r"\S", r"?:", r"\1",
                                           r"\2", r"\A", r"\b",
                                           r"\B", r"\Z", r"\.",
                                           r"\[", r"\]", r"\(",
                                           r"\)", r"\{", r"\}",
                                           r"\+", r"\|", r"\?",
                                           r"\*"]

CHAR_SAMPLE = []
BREAKPOINT = re.compile(
    r"""
    \(.*?\)|
    \[.*?\]|
    \{.*?\}|
    \w+(?=[\(\[\{])?|
    \S+?|
    \.\*\??|
    \.\+\??|
    \.\?\??|
    \\.|
    .*?
    """,
    re.VERBOSE)

MATCH_BRACKETS = {'(': ')', '[': ']', '{': '}'}
CLOSE_BRACKETS = {')', ']', '}'}
REGEX_SEEDER = [
    r".*?",
    r"(?:.*?)",
    r"\w|\s",
    r"(?<.*?)",
    r"(?=.*?)",
    r"(?!.*?)",
    r"(?<=.*?)",
    r"(?<!.*?)",
    ]

LEN_LIMIT = 100

def distribute(distribution):
    global CHAR_SAMPLE
    for item in CHAR_SET:
        if item in distribution:
            CHAR_SAMPLE.extend([item] * distribution[item])
        else:
            CHAR_SAMPLE.append(item)

def rand_index(seq, stop=None):
    if stop is None:
        stop = len(seq)
    try:
        return randrange(0, stop)
    except ValueError:
        return 0

def rand_slice(seq):
    try:
        start = randrange(0, len(seq))
        stop = randrange(start, len(seq))
        return slice(start, stop)
    except ValueError:
        return slice(0,  0)


#Mutation Functions

def replace(seq):
    seq[rand_index(seq)] = choice(CHAR_SAMPLE)

def delete(seq):
    del seq[rand_index(seq)]

def insert(seq):
    seq.insert(rand_index(seq, len(seq) + 1), choice(CHAR_SAMPLE))

def duplicate(seq):
    source = rand_slice(seq)
    seq[source.stop: source.stop] = seq[source]

def swap(seq):
    if len(seq) < 2: return
    a = rand_index(seq, len(seq) - 1)
    seq[a], seq[a + 1] = seq[a + 1], seq[a]

dummy = lambda seq: None

MUTATE = (
    replace,
    delete,
    insert,
    duplicate,
    swap,
    dummy,
    dummy,
    )

def repair_brackets(seq):
    """Attempts to lower the percentage of invalid regexes by
    matching orphaned brackets"""
    
    p_stack, new_seq = [], []
    for item in seq:
        if item in MATCH_BRACKETS:
            p_stack.append(item)
        elif item in CLOSE_BRACKETS:
            while p_stack and MATCH_BRACKETS[p_stack[-1]] != item:
                new_seq.append(MATCH_BRACKETS[p_stack[-1]])
                p_stack.pop()
            if not p_stack:
                continue
            else:
                p_stack.pop()
        new_seq.append(item)
    while p_stack:
        new_seq.append(MATCH_BRACKETS[p_stack.pop()])
    return new_seq

def compress(seq):
    new_seq = [seq[0]]
    last_match = seq[0]
    repeat = 1
    for item in islice(seq, 1, len(seq)):
        if item == last_match:
            repeat += 1
        else:
            if repeat > 1:
                new_seq.extend(list("{{{0}}}".format(repeat)))
            new_seq.append(item)
            last_match = item
            repeat = 1
    else:
        if repeat > 1:
            new_seq.extend(list("{{{0}}}".format(repeat)))
    return new_seq
            
        
def mutate(seq):
    """Random in-place mutation of sequence"""
    if len(seq) > LEN_LIMIT:
        seq[:] = seq[:LEN_LIMIT]
    c = choice(MUTATE)
    c(seq)
        
def crossover(seqA, seqB):
    """Recombination of two sequences at optimal breakpoints
    along each regex strand"""
    
    bpA = [item.start() for item in BREAKPOINT.finditer(''.join(seqA))]
    bpB = [item.start() for item in BREAKPOINT.finditer(''.join(seqA))]
    slObjA = (slice(*item) for item in zip(bpA, bpA[1:]))
    slObjB = (slice(*item) for item in zip(bpB, bpB[1:]))
    slices = zip_longest(
        (seqA[item] for item in slObjA),
        (seqB[item] for item in slObjB),
        fillvalue=[]
        )
    recombinant = (choice(item) for item in slices)
    return list(chain.from_iterable(recombinant))

#Fitness testing

def match_percentage(match):
    """Calculates the percentage a text actually matched
    by a regular expression"""
    
    if match and match.endpos:
        return (match.end() - match.start()) / match.endpos
    else:
        return 0.001

def fitness_test(seq, pos_matches, neg_matches):
    """Scoring algorithm to determine regex fitness"""
    
    try:
        self_str = ''.join(seq)
        regex = re.compile(self_str)
    except (re.error, IndexError):
        seq[:] = repair_brackets(seq)
        try:
            self_str = ''.join(seq)
            regex = re.compile(self_str)
        except (re.error, IndexError):
            return 0.001

    pos_score = sum(match_percentage(regex.search(item))
                    for item in pos_matches) / len(pos_matches) / 3

    neg_score = (1 - sum(match_percentage(regex.search(item))
                    for item in neg_matches) / len(neg_matches)) / 3

    self_score = match_percentage(regex.search(self_str)) / 3
    
    return pos_score + self_score + neg_score

#Population Management

def generate_pop(pos_matches, neg_matches, pop_size):
    sources = (pos_matches, REGEX_SEEDER)
    return [crossover(
        choice(choice(sources)), choice(choice(sources))
        ) for i in range(pop_size)]

def glean_pop(population, cutoff, fit_test, ft_args=()):
    scores = (fit_test(bug, *ft_args) for bug in population)
    ranked = sorted(zip(population, scores), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    maxItem = ranked[0]
    new_pop = next(zip(*ranked))[:cutoff]
    return maxItem, new_pop

def repopulate(population, pop_size):
    cutoff = len(population)
    for i in range(pop_size // cutoff):
        population.extend([crossover(choice(population), choice(population))
                           for i in range(cutoff)])
    population.extend([population[i][:] for i in range(pop_size - len(population))])

#Simulator
def simulate(pos_matches, neg_matches, pop_size=50, cutoff=10, threshold=1.0):
    population = generate_pop(pos_matches, neg_matches, pop_size)
    while True:
        for bug in population:
            mutate(bug)

        #Scoring step
        max_item, population = glean_pop(
            population,
            cutoff,
            fitness_test,
            (pos_matches, neg_matches)
            )

        #Exit condition:
        max_regex, max_score = max_item
        if max_score >= threshold:
            return max_score, max_regex
        """
        print(max_score, ''.join(max_regex))
        input("next?")"""

        #Repopulation Step:
        population = list(population)
        repopulate(population, pop_size)
```

Comment: Is this Python?

Comment: Why isn't the `no_match_list` (or `but_not_these`) variable used in the code?  Is this for python 2.7?

Comment: @Darthfett: Those are just usage examples.

Comment: @Griffin: Yes. It's Python 27. I'm editing my post to indicate that.

Comment: @JoelCornett Writing my own `simulate` function is part of the usage?  Your `simulate` function doesn't use argument #2.

Comment: @Darthfett: No that is an example of how you would call the function. I used variable names that were descriptive of their (hypothetical) contents. My mistake about parameter 2, it was a typo. `no_match` is supposed to be renamed `no_match_list`. Edited

Comment: Why do you call `population = generate_pop(pos_matches, neg_matches, pop_size)`, but the `generate_pop` function never makes use of the `neg_matches` parameter? Also, can you please include an example of calling the function? Could I call it like `simulate(["Hello","World","world"], ["woah","bad","dont match"])`?

Comment: Hey, it's been a few years since I wrote this. Just reading over the code without testing, it appears that yes, you can call the `simulate()` function as you described. And yes, you are right: I don't use the negative data for generating the initial population.

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript regular expression that matches stuff like it.

```
/^\/\^\\\/\\\^[\\\[\]\/\^\${},\dd]{34}$/
```

You can test it like so:

```
(function test() {
    var re =/^\/\^\\\/\\\^[\\\[\]\/\^\${},\dd]{34}$/;
    var m  =/=([^;]+)/.exec(test)[1];
    return re.exec(m);
})();
```

Comment: What is "stuff like it"?  Is this practical or useful in any way?

Comment: @Darthfett: It matches similar regular expressions that attempt to match themselves and this regular expression. No, it's not practical or useful in any way, but the only possible practical or useful, but also interesting, regular expression that matches itself is a regular expression to match regular expressions. Which has been done.